# Laravel, mejorando la relacion recursiva NxM que tengo en mi app

Tags: laravel, eloquent, recursión, relaciones

tengo un problema a la hora de crear unas relaciones entre 2 Tablas (Recursivamente).
Pongo el ejemplo:

Tengo una tabla `Persona` : (`id,nombre,apel1,apel2..`)

Y otra tabla `Parentescos` : (`id,persona_1,persona_2,tipo_parentesco_id`)

Mi idea es que desde la clase **Persona** haya relaciones como : `Padres y hermanos` , para empezar, y ya a partir de ahi podria sacar todo. Tengo una funcionalidad de añadir padre y hermano que funciona, de hecho tengo unas relaciones que de alguna manera pero traen los datos pero no con las estructuras que deseo porque como lo tengo ahora me trae datos de la tabla itnermedia, y se que hay una manera de obviar la tabla intermedia.

Estas son mis dos relaciones en modelo Persona:

```
public function parents(){
    return $this->hasMany(Parents::class,'person_1')
        ->with('person2')
        ->where('parent_type_id',ParentType::PARENT);
}


public function children(){
    return $this->hasMany(Parents::class,'person_2')
        ->with('person1')
        ->where('parent_type_id',ParentType::PARENT);
}
```

Funcionar funcionan pero como digo, en vez de traerme algo asi :

```
$pepe = People::find(3); $pepe->children
[!] Aliasing 'People' to 'App\Models\People' for this Tinker session.
= Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#6951
    all: [
      App\Models\Parents {#7212
        id: 3,
        person_1: 6,
        person_2: 3,
        parent_type_id: 1,
        created_at: "2023-08-27 08:42:55",
        updated_at: "2023-08-27 08:42:55",
        person1: App\Models\People {#7219
          id: 6,
          name: "Julio",
          surname1: "Apellido 1",
          surname2: "Apellido 2",
          birthday: "2023-01-01",
          deathday: null,
          gender_id: 1,
          created_at: "2023-08-27 08:42:54",
          updated_at: "2023-08-27 08:42:54",
        },
      },
      App\Models\Parents {#7213
        id: 5,
        person_1: 5,
        person_2: 3,
        parent_type_id: 1,
        created_at: "2023-08-27 08:42:55",
        updated_at: "2023-08-27 08:42:55",
        person1: App\Models\People {#7221
          id: 5,
          name: "Alicia",
          surname1: "Apellido 1",
          surname2: "Apellido 2",
          birthday: "2023-01-01",
          deathday: null,
          gender_id: 2,
          created_at: "2023-08-27 08:42:54",
          updated_at: "2023-08-27 08:42:54",
        },
      },
    ],
  }
```

Me gustaria que solo trajera el resultado de la relacion final obviando la relacion intermedia llamada `Parents` , con esta imagen igual se entiende mejor :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

DDL DE LA BD

```
create schema familia collate utf8mb4_general_ci;

create table failed_jobs
(
    id bigint unsigned auto_increment
        primary key,
    uuid varchar(255) not null,
    connection text not null,
    queue text not null,
    payload longtext not null,
    exception longtext not null,
    failed_at timestamp default current_timestamp() not null,
    constraint failed_jobs_uuid_unique
        unique (uuid)
)
collate=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

create table genders
(
    id bigint unsigned auto_increment
        primary key,
    name varchar(255) not null,
    created_at timestamp null,
    updated_at timestamp null,
    constraint genders_name_unique
        unique (name)
)
collate=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

create table migrations
(
    id int unsigned auto_increment
        primary key,
    migration varchar(255) not null,
    batch int not null
)
collate=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

create table parent_types
(
    id bigint unsigned auto_increment
        primary key,
    name varchar(255) not null,
    created_at timestamp null,
    updated_at timestamp null
)
collate=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

create table password_reset_tokens
(
    email varchar(255) not null
        primary key,
    token varchar(255) not null,
    created_at timestamp null
)
collate=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

create table people
(
    id bigint unsigned auto_increment
        primary key,
    name varchar(255) not null,
    surname1 varchar(255) not null,
    surname2 varchar(255) not null,
    birthday date not null,
    deathday date null,
    gender_id bigint unsigned not null,
    created_at timestamp null,
    updated_at timestamp null
)
collate=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

create table parents
(
    id bigint unsigned auto_increment
        primary key,
    person_1 bigint unsigned not null,
    person_2 bigint unsigned not null,
    parent_type_id bigint unsigned not null,
    created_at timestamp null,
    updated_at timestamp null,
    constraint parents_parent_type_id_foreign
        foreign key (parent_type_id) references parent_types (id),
    constraint parents_person_1_foreign
        foreign key (person_1) references people (id),
    constraint parents_person_2_foreign
        foreign key (person_2) references people (id)
)
collate=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

create table personal_access_tokens
(
    id bigint unsigned auto_increment
        primary key,
    tokenable_type varchar(255) not null,
    tokenable_id bigint unsigned not null,
    name varchar(255) not null,
    token varchar(64) not null,
    abilities text null,
    last_used_at timestamp null,
    expires_at timestamp null,
    created_at timestamp null,
    updated_at timestamp null,
    constraint personal_access_tokens_token_unique
        unique (token)
)
collate=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

create index personal_access_tokens_tokenable_type_tokenable_id_index
    on personal_access_tokens (tokenable_type, tokenable_id);

create table users
(
    id bigint unsigned auto_increment
        primary key,
    name varchar(255) not null,
    email varchar(255) not null,
    email_verified_at timestamp null,
    password varchar(255) not null,
    remember_token varchar(100) null,
    created_at timestamp null,
    updated_at timestamp null,
    constraint users_email_unique
        unique (email)
)
collate=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```